# Why does pipe not work with cat and locate?

Tags: pipe, cat, locate

I am trying to perform this:

```
locate pg_type.h | cat
```

But this command simply does nothing different than locate pg_type.h

What should I change ? I want to perform `cat pg_type.h` wherever `pg_type.h` may be.

Comment: You are running `locate(1)`, and sending its output to the input of `cat(1)`, which dutifully copies its input to its output. Nothing to see here, move along.

Comment: Also note that [`locate` is not reliable](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/273773/135943) for information about what is on your filesystem *right now*.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
locate -e0 '*/pg_type.h' | xargs -r0 cat
```

`locate pg_type.h` would find all the files with `pg_type.h` in their path (so for instance if there was a `rpg_type.horn` directory, you'd end up displaying all the files in there).

Without `-0` the output of `locate` can't be post-processed because the files are separated by newline characters while newline is a perfectly valid character in a file name.

`cat` without arguments writes to stdout what it reads from stdin, so `locate | cat` would be the same as `locate`, `cat` would just pass the output of `locate` along. What you need is to pass the list of files as *arguments* to `cat`.

That's what `xargs` is typically for: convert a stream of data into a list of arguments. `-r` is to not call `cat` if there's no input. Without `-0` (which like `-r` is not standard but found on many implementations, at least those where xargs is useful to anything), `xargs` would just look for *words* in its input to convert into arguments, where *words* are blank separated and where backslash, single and double quotes can be used to escape those separators, so typically not the format `locate` uses to display file names.

That's why we use the `-0` option for both `locate` and `xargs` which uses the NUL character (which is the only character not allowed in a file path) to separate file names.

Also note that `locate` is not a standard command and there exist a great number of different implementations with different versions thereof and different options and behaviours. The code above applies at least to relatively recent versions of the GNU `locate` and `mlocate` implementations which are the most common on Linux based operating systems at least.

Comment: +1, and answer for all the good details. It happen that I think `locate` is much faster than `find`, and I still have hesitations with `find` that I should learn however, that's sure...

Comment: A bit late to the discussion but remember that `locate` uses a previously constructed index/cache as its source of data (usually rebuild regularly with a `cron` job) which can be updated manually (typically with a `sudo updatedb` - it often needs elevated privileges to read some areas of the file-system!)  _c.f._ `find` walks and reports on the file-system at run time so it will return current details at the time it finds them.  In comparison `locate` is faster at the time you use it (especially if you have to refine/repeat your search) whereas `find` is more current in data it returns...

Answer (score 7):

Your command passes the output of `locate` to `cat` on standard-in. That's not what you want. What *you* want is to pass the output of `locate` to `cat` as an *argument*.

I believe the way to do that is with `xargs`:

```
locate pg_type.h | xargs cat
```

Comment: You can also do this with backticks or `$()`, eg `cat $(locate pg_type.h)`.

Comment: That assumes none of the paths returned by locate contain any space, tab, newline, blackslash, single or double quote characters. And for `$()` (@goldilocks), no spc, tab, newline or globbing (`*`, `?`, `[`) characters.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas : Yep.  But who would put silly things like that in a path? ;) ;)

Comment: @goldilocks, Windows/Mac users or anybody that may want to exploit the bug that you're introducing. For instance, if you run that line as `root` and the output ends up in somewhere world-readable, then somebody may want to create a file called `/tmp/ /etc/shadow /pg_type.h` to be able to have a look at the content of the `/etc/shadow` file. Remember some bugs end up being security vulnerabilities, some of which end up exploited. Lets try and have as few bugs as possible in the first place. And that starts with teaching good practice here (or at least mention the limitations/risks).