# Cannot delete file, but can delete parent directory

Tags: locate

So basically, I'm trying to delete the files:

```
/var/lib/mysql/db/nomNomina2.*
```

and when I look for them with locate, I get the following output:

```
/var/lib/mysql/db/nomNomina2.MYD
/var/lib/mysql/db/nomNomina2.MYI
/var/lib/mysql/db/nomNomina2.frm
```

but then I try to

```
 $ rm -fv  /var/lib/mysql/db/nomNomina2.frm
```

I get no output, but the files still show when using locate.

Notice that I can create and delete a file with the same filename in the same location, but it will still show when using locate, and I won't be able to create another table with the same name.

Any ideas what could be causing this? filesystem mess? how to correct it?

Comment: Try updating the database used by **locate** using **updatedb**.

Comment: The locate database is updated on a schedule; may be daily -- check cron or use vikyboss's suggestion to update is manually b

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`locate` is **not dependable** for live, current information about what files are present on your system.  Information is cached in a database.

Also consider the famous line, with link:

> It's not working! [Should I blame caching?](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/)

For actual current information on what files/directories exist on your box *right now*, use `ls` or `find` or `stat` or `test -e filename && echo it is there` or even `printf %s\\n *`.  Pretty much *anything* except `locate` will give you up-to-date information about your filesystem.

See also `LESS=+/BUGS man locate` which (on my system) reads in part:

> ```
> BUGS
>  The locate program may fail to list some files that are present, or may
>  list files that have been removed from the system.  This is because
>  locate only reports files that are present in the database...
> ```

You can run `updatedb`, but honestly if you know exactly where the files are and you are using `locate` to find them...you are simply doing it wrong.  `locate` tells you a path.  It tells you nothing about the existence or nonexistence of files at that path.  If you already know the path to the file, you don't need `locate`, do you?

The *purpose* of locate is to "find filenames quickly", not necessarily accurately or dependably.

---

<sub>Note: I'm not saying "don't use `locate`."  It does have a purpose, when you have no idea where on your system a certain file might be.  But once you get the pathname from `locate`, it has served its purpose and you now need to use *other* tools to examine/verify/etc. the file you've found.</sub>

Comment: Some versions of locate have a -e option to make it check for a file's existence before printing a line. But, you're still stuck with the reverse problem: files created since the last updatedb run won't appear, unless you're using a version of locate that ties into FSEvents or similar.

Comment: Well, guess one learns new things everyday. I wasn't so sure why "ls" or "find" weren't returning any results. 

The interesting thing is that mysql prevented me from creating a table with the same name until I ran "updatedb".

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

locate command does not search the files on disk rather it searches for file paths in a database. The database is a file that contains information about the files and their path on your system.

So one limitation of the ‘locate’ command is its dependency on the database which can be updated by another utility ‘updatedb’. Hence, in order to get the latest and reliable results from ‘locate’ command the database on which it works should be updated at regular intervals.

hence, after deleting the file, you should check the file existence using #find command which searches the file in real time. #find /var/lib/mysql/db/ -iname "nomNomina2.*"